# Android Backup and Restore

Tags: android, backup, restore

I have rooted android phone. I backed up a application, uninstalled the application from the phone and restored it back the way it was there in the phone(using backup including changes to packages.list and packages.xml). The restored application is not showing up immediately but shows up after reboot of the phone.

Is there any service that has to be restarted to recognize the presence of the app immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the task manager and kill the home/launcher application. That would usually do it.

And I believe https://android.stackexchange.com/ is the place for that type of question as this is meant for programming related questions.

Comment: question moved to: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13179/android-backup-and-restore